# Ошибка 403 при попытке зайти на сайт, располагающемся на Github

Tags: html, веб-программирование, github, github-pages

Причём данная ошибка непостоянна, и возникает через раз в любой момент времени
В Github Pages всё настроено как надо, все файлы сайта располагаются в нужной директории. В DNS домена все нудные записи созданы (четыре а-записи по IP гитхаба и cname-запись к "бесплатному" домену github pages)
Говорят, что данная ошибка возникает из-за кэширования сайта. Вставлял определённые строки для отключения, но ошибка всё равно всплывает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, спустя неделю мучений, я наконец-то нашёл причину - гитхаб не выдаёт защищённое соединение на привязанные домены (на свой бесплатный .github.io наоборот), из-за чего сайт выдавал сабжевую ошибку: при переходе по https-соединению вы поймаете 403, в то время как по соединению без шифрования сайт работает нормально.
Для решения данной проблемы подключайте какой-нибудь Cloudflare к домену вашего сайта, дабы он получил сертификат и возможность работать по https. Думаю, про работу с Cloudflare объяснять не нужно, там всё интуитивно понятно. Единственное: не забудьте добавить все A-записи от вашего домена в Cloudflare, так как автоматически они не заносятся, иначе сайт перестанет работать